# How can I run Azure Funcions 3.0 on macOS

Tags: azure-functions

I have start a simple project where I connect to my database and send some emails. Running locally (macOS) only works on old versions and it will not work on production. If I upgrade the packages it will stop work locally but it will work on production.

Old packages on production I get the follow error

```
System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform
```

New packages on local I get the follow error

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: provider

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The old versions

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ably.io" Version="1.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The new versions

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ably.io" Version="1.1.18" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.2">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>  
</Project>
```

Another detail, is that I do have the newest Azure Functions Core Tools installed

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (3.0.2245 Commit hash: 1d094e2f3ef79b9a478a1621ea7ec3f93ac1910d)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.13139.0
```

... but when I run the project it shows

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.7.1948 Commit hash: 29a0626ded3ae99c4111f66763f27bb9fb564103)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12888.0
```

My startup class

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            string connection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<BaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        }
    }
```

What could I be missing?

Is that a macOS issue?

Comment: First, you should update `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` to the version 3.1. This does not have a dependency on System.Data.SqlClient anymore

Comment: and also Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to 3.0.5

Comment: @silent, oops, sorry I've just past the wrong versions in the question. Just to be clear, at the new versions it's all update.

Comment: but then there is still something wrong with your dependencies. The 3.x EF Core packages do not depend on System.Data.SqlClient anymore.

Comment: If I can give you an advice that I wish someone would have given me it to install Intellij Rider (with Azure Toolkit) and ditch VS. It's just plain wonderful!